# error c2065 :'LONG64' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have a c2965 problem that I need to get solved. I am new to c++ and when I try to compile my script I get the following error.

error c2065:'long64' : undeclared identifier

on the line

```
long64 *x, *y;
```

I am not sure what have caused this and it seems that this is a relatively uncommon issue. I work on a 64bit system and uses a 64bit compiler installed in visual studio 2008.

If anyone know the cause, please answer this. Thanks beforehand

Comment: Is it `LONG64` or `long64`? Neither are standard, and no standard 64-bit minimum type came until C++11. If you're talking about the Windows API type `LONG64`, you'll have to at least include the header.

Comment: Where did you get this declaration from? What made you type `long64`?

Comment: Sorry a typo, changed to long64, the code is a mex submission in matlab and I am not completely sure who the writer is, I have just began to learn c++ and have never worked in 64bit before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an 'undeclared identifier' error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197030/what-is-an-undeclared-identifier-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks I will remove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear enough: the compiler does not see the definition of name `long64`, It is possible that the corresponding definition is present in some header file that you forgot to include in the module.
You can try to include header `<cstdint>` and use type `int64_t` instead of `long64`